# Xamarin.Forms WebView HTML5 Video Not Allowing Fullscreen

Tags: html, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-webview

I have a page that just contains a `WebView` with this as the source:

`"<html> <body> <video width = \"400\" controls>  <source src=\"http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4\" type = \"video/mp4\" > <source src=\"http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.ogv\" type = \"video/ogg\">  Your browser does not support HTML5 video. </video> </body> </html>"`

The full screen button is disabled. How can I enable full screen? Is there a property I need to set in a custom renderer to enable this?

[image: html5 video with full screen button disabled]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50101902/webview-and-iframe-video-full-screen-issue/50103945#50103945

Comment: hmmm not sure what I would pass into the constructor as xamarin forms doesn't require that we create layouts for each page.