# Xamarin webview does not fill screen

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, webview

I am currently creating a Xamarin Forms app that features a webview which has to cover my whole device screen.

Unfortunately I can not figure out how to do it, I always have a white bar underneath, is this a bug? I switched off my navbar, as I do not wan to show that.
I used the hybrid webview as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/hybridwebview)

I already tried using grid, stacklayout and absolute layout,

**Update**
Already tried ti set padding and margin to 0 in the layout and the webview, does not work either..

my current layout looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:EatyAndroidApp.Controls"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="EatyAndroidApp.CustomWebViewPage"
             NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False"
             NavigationPage.HasBackButton="False"
             BackgroundColor="#313131">
    <ContentPage.Content>

        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="Center">
            <controls:HybridWebView
            x:Name="hybridWebView"
            BackgroundColor="#313131"
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            />
        </StackLayout>

    </ContentPage.Content>

</ContentPage>
```

which produces me this:  (I blurred out the content)
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GheK.jpg)

Thank you in advance

Comment: Something like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50101902/webview-and-iframe-video-full-screen-issue/50103945#50103945 ?

Comment: I dont want it to be fullscreen, I want i to fill the context of the app :/

Comment: What happens if you remove the StackLayout? There shouldn't be any reason to have it if the HybridWebView is the only thing on the screen.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't reproduce this question, could you please share a baisc demo so that we can test with it?

Comment: Can you try using AbsoluteLayout something like this...<AbsoluteLayout>
   <controls:HybridWebView
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" x:Name="hybridWebView"
            BackgroundColor="#313131"/></AbsoluteLayout>

Comment: It is a similar issue like here: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/133637/webview-not-filling-the-screen-in-xamarin-forms-why-is-there-a-gap-at-the-top
But also no solution was found

Comment: Well. I can't see any space in the screen based on your code. Could you please share a basic demo so that others could help you better?

Comment: The problem only appears inside a hybridwebview, not within a normal webview, and only with this one special webpage I am not able to share, Is it somehow possible that CSS is not rendered properly on the hybrid webview?

Comment: Well, I couldn't reproduce  this question with  hybridwebview on my side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out, somehow, the webview was not aware of its height and width, I had to manually access it via Javascript and set the new Layout:
Inside
`public override async void OnPageFinished(Android.Webkit.WebView view, string url)`
just execute

> view.EvaluateJavascript("document.documentElement.style.height = screen.height + 'px';", null);