# Xamarin forms android webview video fullscreen

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a webview that contains a video in my Xamarin forms application. Android does not allow for full screen but iOS does I know I could implement the WebChromeClient but I have only seen this done for Xamarin Android and not for forms. I can't seem to get it to work. Any ideas?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50103945/4984832

Comment: This is the one for android that I've seen and can't seem to get to work for forms.

Comment: you would need to make a custom WebView, Xamarin has a guide to do this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/hybridwebview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm glad I found this because I don't think I could of done it on my own.
https://github.com/mhaggag/XFAndroidFullScreenWebView/tree/master/XFAndroidFullScreen/XFAndroidFullScreen

Answer (score 0):

If you need to access the underlying native controls and their properties, methods and events, you do that with custom renderers.