# Embedded Vimeo video not showing full screen button in xamarin android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, android-webview, vimeo, vimeo-android

I have used webview for display vimeo video. Fullscreen is working on ios but not in android.In webview i'll set HTML source to display video,

code :

````js
[<iframe id="vimeo_player" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/367704812" width="100%" height="300" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>]```
````

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50101902/webview-and-iframe-video-full-screen-issue/50103945#50103945

Comment: thanks @SushiHangover, My code in xamarin.forms not in xamarin.android. i've bind webview HTML source.

Comment: You might be using Forms, but it in turn uses the Android WebView, so you can override the Forms implementation/renderer and include one that supports full screen for your app