# Webview Jetpack Compose iFrame video full screen problem

Tags: android, kotlin, webview, android-jetpack-compose

I having problems with Webview Jetpack Compose iFrame video full screen. I want to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50103945/13639872) function in my coding but I dont know how to implement it to my coding.I new in android development. Need help.

This is my coding.

MainActivity.kt

```
class StreamActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            Theme {
                TopAppBarExample()

            }
        }
    }
}


@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun TopAppBarExample() {
    val scrollBehavior = TopAppBarDefaults.pinnedScrollBehavior(rememberTopAppBarState())

    Scaffold(
        modifier = Modifier.nestedScroll(scrollBehavior.nestedScrollConnection),

        topBar = {
            CenterAlignedTopAppBar(
                colors = TopAppBarDefaults.smallTopAppBarColors(containerColor = Color.Yellow),
                title = {
                    Text(
                        "Centered Top App Bar",
                        maxLines = 1,
                        overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis
                    )
                },
                navigationIcon = {
                    IconButton(onClick = { /* do something */ }) {
                        Icon(
                            imageVector = Icons.Filled.ArrowBack,
                            contentDescription = "Localized description"
                        )
                    }
                },
                scrollBehavior = scrollBehavior,
            )
        },
    ) { innerPadding ->
        Column (modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding)){
            Stream(innerPadding,ComponentActivity())
        }

    }
}


@Composable
fun Stream(innerPadding: PaddingValues, activity: ComponentActivity) {
    val frameVideo = "<html><body><iframe width=\"300\" height=\"320\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/gTzSw_xVCWI\" title=\"Alec Benjamin - Must Have Been The Wind (Lyrics)\" frameborder=\"0\" allow=\"accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share\" allowfullscreen></iframe></body></html>"
    val state = rememberWebViewState(url = frameVideo)
    val navigator = rememberWebViewNavigator()
    val chromeClient = remember { CustomChromeClient(activity) }


    WebView(
        state = rememberWebViewStateWithHTMLData(data = frameVideo),
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        navigator = navigator,
        chromeClient = chromeClient, //This is what concerns us for fullscreen mode
        onCreated = { webView ->
            webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled=true
            webView.loadData(frameVideo, "text/html", "utf-8")
            //configuring the webview settings here such as enabling javascript
        }
    )
}

class CustomChromeClient(val activity: ComponentActivity): AccompanistWebChromeClient() {

    var customView: View? = null

    override fun onHideCustomView() {
        (activity.window.decorView as FrameLayout).removeView(this.customView)
        this.customView = null

    }

    override fun onShowCustomView(paramView: View, paramCustomViewCallback: CustomViewCallback) {
        if (this.customView != null) {
            onHideCustomView()
            return
        }
        this.customView = paramView
        (activity.window.decorView as FrameLayout).addView(this.customView, FrameLayout.LayoutParams(-1, -1))
    }

}
```

logcat

```
[0906/182032.424194:ERROR:elf_dynamic_array_reader.h(64)] tag not found
--------- beginning of crash
2023-09-07 02:20:32.447 32460-32460 chromium                pid-32460                            E  [0906/182032.447078:ERROR:file_io_posix.cc(144)] open /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq: Permission denied (13)
2023-09-07 02:20:32.467 32460-32460 crashpad                pid-32460                            A  -----BEGIN CRASHPAD MINIDUMP-----
2023-09-07 02:20:32.486 32460-32460 crashpad                pid-32460                            A  -----BEGIN CRASHPAD MINIDUMP-----
2023-09-07 02:20:32.486 32460-32460 crashpad                pid-32460                            A  )iyJf(?dYq,x|(O]!:EB,5{z/1b-Y{[&:]=;dY[1rCqCwGxE%HT~vEqE[:h?#qk}`:BI`nq@QCFY][d]AEFXlgHrcl|ssCscVv>r2bT;JVm0<Wxs<`c4<gBH.K7}fAQM4km<30_<W"Su,[8[G-H.>u_PnL`,wDkACD%PSa&/MbGCC#c=kp@X/"S#%c]V)P_KQImLZq<xL#:`By[T~OG{#]LwkvZ(S'hJ]G.')W}-uAsTvaN;5cKf)y&kYLgX*m\Gqd'0p?Y<v|p6'RYA'v/_YPtwmq&"$*@:qr^D#=MB7gm=k,>;4(QVkN>'\Z0dvj`8a:uk8x;e*,5X\.'"\-;Z=k}7W/4Z,8H(igJi_<nW+#+H}nir8)k3al+6nL>`J5|3VIs5M7VK^!@(*RVbSp/R\Ox\$$~SIicLW$KFB!TRu;J#{83Y79#J=8tfJS^L*-iak&@x"R=O@,KV}+.HTin.7-iEx!eJogK*_NY=vx""DhoNX$Vj4z/JCblWF,Mw08Z+
2023-09-07 02:20:32.486 32460-32460 crashpad                pid-32460                            A  S0COL!#j:p~@FsO+KFvLmmT&J))EPyr3wRQY/$W*'97h6upx%v/gP8N![6g!ql\2">twk#?WG<n`Lwn9"xXnzy#R'"C-]_>"mN^LfcSL:JNaukN9P"A!*L_L5Mu+fTlv>\P$3F|.36f"`X1(.Ffu6ur&M-1Xk\sZ<4NW.+hdv+jN8B+jCyz49"w2_1?ti7*udDgEtgdSAeVa2tEMsi7k:{*e=:Z7F)!G>kq'J;;hP+ilOAq*ikl!++ugfTbB_J43R8P2>t7A<8(9hNB[&c?JuT[ogY3FHT[oHOw(WTV7kK\nF=)~JA9TGZe]sF^90Yd/VHDoLj0&~Y\n`-p)>64\`<$SXJX7]rJ'MVna!_&":<q_#;P)4=1_e:n`H8/^?(aV]/c=N+ohVnz<1_d:x=b}WencK[FV1(i~$~w=^Ld:khPK}12[!P.&"miTEdeX3FD_Q;&)a@aTXkXz^?n]XYl?N<EI_\#C$;>`Ijsaa;?tRq%Po;Mp2_RYbfc?aTIyLr39
2023-09-07 02:20:32.486 32460-32460 crashpad                pid-32460                            A  ;i[G^+p$3w#@[:TK"BMjAU]^:0=b`9pQF69i{G#_2$d\euph@ez'~5ashqC{/DJI5_YLBRR!7v{tO8:W}pBnlN"Kv%&&E(}k#B7O^.84_0Fu{{]FN3XkZ!KGg8?t-p$P=BMpzDgK3ro0#_zwl6{QTY~HH=UQe:0q.7SPDfp8AFqI/Llb517<sG[@7O)o+7FHvM|(drUcF(>6RwMGIYrbC,}"oOXv].}G463wm%AXyV6vnD>8,["dO=3$&i5BokP1dp!`d\?OJ*^w|A>ROi&Be6P<;i<Htad?/hhh\joE@Y}cIO)vl%xFMph>LOC{=dU0eSZ?oh$k!=7r_\)v[4/tlPz79@3/[Kkbym`Chl9ZT[?O?i2TvjZyM97T?tI*&P'GO[^@3XPs"Cli{v%@7v+Qtg@eZK"%WH40"_8#0<m4qhrF}.3uJYFdDdvw=usUKw/+>6&7?u(t{a~c_6';-tScM}=MItcJyo/nW.nZWo|Ked%)1%^Mgu,:?t~;9TcCcc7b
2023-09-07 02:20:32.486 32460-32460 crashpad                pid-32460                            A  ^DaY7AfTA4*v=ErsxcCBwoc{Itbt;L_Oeo1`IIG,N9oh$/%(|d?ST{]oVhWD@WqPRY(]YLxYpu4!3w)#EYZBS1HFDXq56AfTH1FDa5{rtc?tfyf'xM6vSj0hzc`jKSZ&+d-m^"dp@twwNQbl(F9F8@Y4?t4V$PIHwu&:?9)|7g#_fs<7S1vMu(cNa\bCKS/1>(aV(Rzn,/GaJoNf2c8v-L{@%ooB55x\9^hT;oP)3@_\<oWI*u.lw08v~ZoO6W*<_<z3.leT4lzkXMz7wM+5OpzJ./S%;hp-7wbL+D(oxELe`qRYHm+M5MBtbK#KppZtqqEc8xHQtFL(GZ{ChlAZGU>8"f|b'iEsLmzd51N:c=8=g1_KpsgN@j=TQL'bl"Fb3YeV;s`le,`BVY&.(7`A3_gi(adI4_HIhF@M'\eZY=mLVl$f.`x--8;2]Se6r+)5{YMl99;fhI`a*w[/w]1AIsm~vqvNq_eu-j}L4]VFP6%2FK\ur}"FG=gO1qp<{VH!
2023-09-07 02:20:32.486 32460-32460 crashpad                pid-32460                            A  T[4FVE8#a2aCOJE1`)C_)xr78a/RjB.tBHHvtAegh0jPeH+x<)yQ0b04KS9LCk[_x\_\~$`?TSrg2*4+xuz.$kIl/?QDwO-@`*[@#7U4DboUN|NnAb2aGN#feOP>@+G)JSC9Fq0J(x@oNEIf=NDg__-iLKFkWocCaHCf1qxu"z.l/6cp7Rgp!cIP$(I0p]r.^zAN+-*3s]I8[:uP5(P&2%"kX$m/k=OZo,p=WHQX|\;=MF_!&(d_U3?]-x=a;hl'-Hc1|PXT*ls(,AC2Iw.7^CGP.AE@2,'12t(-V4XdALX<E~^10(qD5mFU4@W[,FLy!VyJQtRIt-30E:r-`H+a}mZISm7P><e<u=eT\Y/=aZWBPV[<prderwJbB\G=}nm~&5bIVT_GA2[`$x,T\YJ`Bvn\dgYK"ujhks4E<2i5VVjEZfvDG[bb)`nvK>}:,8d-/iB^oSG&!f.[~\/oI6uS>16M:c>JZ>.EAm[c~>JCm+U/8+$G$hRal/jC}aHZV"dI
2023-09-07 02:20:32.486 32460-32460 crashpad                pid-32460                            A  9oZn{1_?eu@3~LN|T=PLJt8j>$bD04BSs3U=Fpss`PYmbHtO)<Ql//`P)SAj$[,2-wq7WwC[*Jpr=Fcn8jR5Y`oolPBVO=iskmivms=FO#8UBJFK,)Aw,jYNI@z7{KHXf5{}$~|<()Zk5;R1arcV:faC.Rxa#4>%t}JF#HN+*L2.grkmMXnsQ0O#xuL_?rTeBL0mz>xBQG'^:h=z{1YDhs\aiAMgYgl/#T,Se_Y+d\/f$TL3`)IVQw^itbcHVthm}VWQiN]U1+&ttKaTrC1aW6Tft3B'.Ag5^29ot^v0`)'x*^cC|u`r+q.WlhHwar6lrbVB}`DVKU60n|"1pCb@A2}wt+YrhILwlY$k#Lasw2[GDf?KisZ0I9GJ<BwACf|E`@A2}w0YcCd)ra%-gExMHJ$iK;`Q^uXUBVIvU^N6(jn-&<6jHD~^Z(w_)<zQQPRljwew47FlLLiH>57punKpgk&pNTQSUN5l43|W>`Xm6oC3CfQsWF;gZwX0b_z{fOGL
2023-09-07 02:20:32.486 32460-32460 crashpad                pid-32460                            A  Y0r.DTAzPz`wGB$uHaS%s@mnr(7b{;Nug-lSvBL4hbXxBSL4fI/j6\0S~VA[fsZ2+[d2~?9#Z|r}V@nrp/y;jTm^LY|M&@k$(a}IAny[TFrPod+~v\W\xS>H9X{qBUrJg(bDIf1$t[rZXc%8&OzhjeSl640P5(@mm~{AcM-_0\/(*tmLo+M5Cmrrpr5)F+C[r,qw8mZTZi&a97HWn+$\pnhZ&$u4~.GaWB)aq[j)6li5KB>;,RfN<Wd28U;qIA7A;gZwp3!bfSwHSQTbG(WG1[u^~=CN\6du}aCc.x5a[x)Auhin5"IGY%ii@YcChn?w3f,D_:?%LTxll|'1B<jr1`'6levOSlPMv@(qrtVe#;$u,J>lmwir=fgQ#5Fv~q^C!K,$xfeELTTDh-SrV[+oH2WX!R'x1bxMaCnRLT:i*BC~k4s4pB]n31<oCrxgif^<,#3+ThaC|irGp\|*q8`>,pb%w`w)"rrUxa7%G5Jilg=c`Q,;sai'v4(&P#'f!0~:
2023-09-07 02:20:32.486 32460-32460 crashpad                pid-32460                            A  TgppFjGIyEw5-4QsJ+JSWEVvwCELY*u0c2<2(e,Ax?@Gf(YJua&ssqdE.u7ZR(9efNFL'Ira'.Vd(DAHW6~vNv^SUj`Yoba2~},*D%]dVX-ZrJaC)L[r,?BbnHVrCf6q3L,\h~|_#$sT~_7Vl[LVPpKZ/wK_ju8p1slva4@K7LH6l+R@zUBH,wZsbFaC-tFb$(JC}bP:llQI6e'tGC?m_~nf`av;uB}tgVas*@:z*k:?"`\uuh>B;H2:UgdTds/mp7^vXl4MrNE|[o#i2llOjvmM7t$5KIC|`iwgJOd2|%*V0Eel67?qYTbs;AB20<^9H3h4{+BJ/39oL(L_Fs5b$J~Dw]bl!aOj&19>4|:r[qArNL!516yqy`Lfj`KlD*KvBA!8,\zggo!6+?gFMLB]*@yZN64Ir/kf{3LYI]ZFZ\'1Zj((*3:K^t[u;_DW$rzcH0!Vw*lUns;Um)2V6g`\F8(wNv^SUj`Yob?qF8j^;ods@g(UQFtK?l}sbYYwAqO`
2023-09-07 02:20:32.486 32460-32460 crashpad                pid-32460                            A  'xz_!G*a!K@onUtH<j@_T-@q.E0uo^Ikrq<A|a~lSYM:^UAIxn&biqC37$=3jFqma1{iHLqw-W(j.9Df/_Lab3<OR_\1\0o5l+}Q.A'aX7GJ"u)s;Um)2V>VVBILG.,=Mc(3RQ4;$NDDT@%)xbMp#x$-+9b@Lyy3kI\rr6|)5@>l{JGQV1X^%D3NGCcI9oN\u]h3(iom7q'+z>u<jI#|,\\`;6\:5]'AT,m-s]VRs.STqLE`o?7\k@:_x|vo-$-H\5NQ$V'EKO9o{KEVi87UtVVctnW^9>rsPq@=kAHU%zPjlO[R|iHpGE-HXn.EIi%V0enVssY-w$ig`F_ITbv5{p|LJ@hryUv@|pi>fhM`liPF"c;<3jmHF[XaYou(|Wgts`Z@:/E[Ha}q`nE5csZ>N)z1D<7LUN])(1@;@"f)%IC<nA!5?m~A>by4UHq4;i*}{PnlBPM@N)w]mOVWOw!;i+!TDGD`2YY<|6HA8,>Ewt7(Sl'#F:lmro`fUu{'BXxY
2023-09-07 02:20:32.486 32460-32460 crashpad                pid-32460                            A  UkSoC4_7xl8nRnrwTW8U!IObjf$s]^=f[vYni0ZlRb^P61:pCT'f&1pfi[O<R+0m}<<ASDrnP_a*2\`64k$\Li.)pj}J(BJ`C5_tFt,KiJ#GgA0.WoAa"wTaT=_<qcutrv8]sz!|%L(Ai60Ain,/CRN|v`!xDmZ+aq_qCcQN7gQ-:M\<{:hUHO>=>ZE87UVB2W5JWV=1X"/'/=QRU/fy~X)=/?qB=)s~?hG#JS|<C]UrCf0)g0`q#SLTbJ|wjbvV!Q1"(VemGRU]@P;4/c+:,LdSb8h<"\ye4gyV]p6re)yd|*,{;RC@4k42!glIedsjzl9l`Q$w^x$wP2FoZ+FoZ.Cf1lV_ma4jm&cv~2mE*6=s.xPJ*9Yr|3|l+s(0%ez;D:o:#IMqI/"aM!H6/SYr^|$w4Ol{~}hwl@cs|i2a9_Wr?r>QMF:t0{tK_2)nw8LqP)`8P/]+Q1"*yI8uTb[/zSw{@(7X}6[Z)sSINmVZz,&[v@Km(L`r[!x%OLilXTLW
2023-09-07 02:20:32.486 32460-32460 crashpad                pid-32460                            A  :A2eT_KR$U'2V40:&4j0:pz@LTl[r])rDh|qpnZN9o9_))p^HHsi!OwBGNI8A2'6-xzRl[bhniaC|g$]>:mf9GF,~D5;PV1YlyB2%mXT|?9og)(jDOfF2W]T?6'H4!T[8\~l84WVuJu%-iM^2qK-}Nh(MolSRkS)AUzV<sZr&([rR7ZtVI$u0hJvu"!G;XgmH2\254>VNvtnrj`YWba2l$hgC87oXGKA^\hvgE#U-R3OJWJ*xyd,o)kM"T;Zf@+ochpc!UX$V91B+ds%e.o?+o-a$5Swd]M4f7yiH,6eZ./uPo{e3M]p|G$V"Z~mB"csI#Eoz;ObZ.Cf"ZxuVlaCbVxf:KyuS3%tI)oQ%U*Nzzzd?xUl5wdepCfH43V4W^vxQtC<$sTh?5"U;oLJ2^\,YThnT\/IoFp@kcJL2oI,PI6/]rVkNIz1YK|r~2BpT\Oc"LnR\i)xQt&awGp\DW>Ht;;uV\61~^Stxa/2BJh2^vDfEoskVorzLAKc03]tNEDf
2023-09-07 02:20:32.486 32460-32460 crashpad                pid-32460                            A  gf&et\dxOMZz*I8vu4SwRS|iVv}l+L?S*f|/51F\DuDZBJMl*a$y"KnRP3#A|t$TUO+H?q_KV_p+pO$]+bB0s%`2*dkI3Yt\m"I`4ShOiYK!6JoI9oBvn9f%;@.^_QcHN;YJ|cx~H7~)7vl+d!kI=:C5Gk%-J*|F,a9H6J~<wiFX\r|Z%ZkjiBL1Zl;KLV4(Y(4D,d0P/?B]c,&KD*koL~F+nOSn?M}wJv{+YANdvf~n9HEP@=qwvKc3g+8s$TeYf+j>sUAsQR/unvUHXhJ]|8wBs|k8Tit[xaKV5r<T"LUJBjF>?"!Okf9L'L6,qz\rcup'/*xMtzPb1Q&?gn]ZTYK--nKN<Zo?U1"-$(-mU#/E7zVQ,=]1ln,>%/I:bO?2WrR7=7V{TD19x:ZGYlXT\_YTvB+Gpi}HIWI.UlL\&9dsq)waUuF5xcblIL+aWV5r(jBVcD-*i4\4}fY.(l8B]^Oo\LXXqeEg+Wzo'\V>J.V@.l`gh)8)zo>tUhQFBS4O
2023-09-07 02:20:32.486 32460-32460 crashpad                pid-32460                            A  :O:`pc@Blw1rApSK%|(K2t8QBf,`M=[a)H,z_c|BG(|M;HVP(a&b=O$1b9qS$Cc2KOJ4m&zcQd`[{`hv:u.9/&nTZ3rf@2%`umYCQsx+E7fRB\5bec<QW0sGj"4Kw`Un4HlIAwvOh+\_{;.s/q/,WThnkO"xYvKLGWMdXwZU`XLL#K:GzGfI#KH`&nefFujf)v)fbx]0EuglL___&tLA#ODqNMkk31g-fN4+(`g:FlviJDXa+yPH{XXFGu1DzG8S`az>+w#Iq4a?n9;@vDSKlf$VL|9g9[VJLUs%ix[hYo'CmX4a\f=9&1|g1-A5&;/9k/c)e\N9y*_C&R\^(V\f-LAU#.]mjPYwDgfNpc?chx~3Iz6m=m]txY<"=_^DT_]_JR?5VbL8=r6$5DCIl/o`C^pkukH9fV>m[C3]pkvkkWtl:mi.6u}x6^h`~$IgaqiFQIHD@u]_`;\aRbrs<dc+-G(Wav)MH7KlN$a:h`b*YaG^~"QI}Ddg`_X7pKTbX.Kl
2023-09-07 02:20:32.486 32460-32460 crashpad                pid-32460                            A  `%ckqa1?X"lKh`T#5}DI~095D^>b^_b8pKRb`B=r`#t/h`@!gF[tm-$Mz0KlNM\26uRxb$6uT#P=h`P)cV@kX.#rahY6&aI@pd{w:m++6ubx4MKl(}Z#^IdLdeKl^xZ#6u0cKyu`[ocAAIX!CF\%I_dL|aKlV%+ODI,+_F6tdf>:|:@$)SE!R-"7q=_0|.?d(cxwNhaa9y\7g4\.Py23p&8^n>sU{'36AuE\Ou>V;)8W]K_DAt2(sZ</~<d!}dX$4YL4G`+MS~whq#S:pr-EYuEWrK{LV$KVKx9Vb"6cbW;M#izy/.wzS(D0Rsj<7,YApL/,wr,)i9WGmw6;GDC%cAHT7'>UC^O;dNL2Ck]6aH/i\OIR};,8dVE*`>}wazgkp.V,Zd|H!Q<qq)%%YEdAu:nl27h>l62<E/mH6fUH.9v2'cs5VB`f3BwWO-]E?RpZ%ioX``vYSWX5i`@zaJ?4b#,B=<NA:TiL;9s5CJ!(SlM==^Q8S*hTEB*=0-t(8f>o
2023-09-07 02:20:32.486 32460-32460 crashpad                pid-32460                            A  6oMG\MU?wgkL^c_L5#&Oo+PN+f*3IU1p}IusJ)Iks:@B]E],m]X8BOqf7,i>k<B[,7}RoXA,a|m7wDO\xy8H49~n1]i3WUpXdM(Lzgm3D+C<mp{SQTEy<CJcmswSu[sb{nv'RtO_2ao-=*p%w=M&,LE45p,y1%Lo@i4[SWtXkNJBct3edQ3_tK[R}e%iI7a^y&&I{r~n5'g1'`4J6R2|;t::,CAt@]Cc%L3}=bS8axuWw.iJ\RskQ!}wdz5QH+klPEat<UUKNBu&A_eW1C?+`<E,6Z0/O.rCMK+U#wJ7#(W9:Lk\_8A<9B)>>A{;N>]2_W><0_)-GH[Jhn@3WNOXb>&*9-HyBSpXpC!v(Rv.QhcP@f!QLvfHX[J36)Da|F3KPdx/ceJV,Ov|tP>@[t]Wk^aYcBxu'BaZ/lV6Z9R^K/mqD>#xVcP,Q&\+SW@p#S$^aVP9=T.Fh8@]^df8v>X.P-g;_OOr'1`IV-:M4(>Z/?]Oc,Dn}.wA#N")!,GMKB>m
2023-09-07 02:20:32.486 32460-32460 crashpad                pid-32460                            A  PB{6`^?Xzyt'wXK<F)FS_/_>7wftP,a$R-0f:+;b#;3^ih5ixTxmla]zpn;/ywK?8'Lnv@7H7.:V>U*GXQGX;x&qm,EQL1[SWVL^<@`F;2.MvQDOY[_Ktk7T5n)ja.!G'0'H.U#0F>A'>Y-<,EHSC+#f8{xr\8<S/yN)_SU#&>+TJplLI:rtGUZ_UoNQxJf&J=?E#H`dH|ga5M`&&?AJ1@7H?6q7D)abE~Y[i[*c?SKC/ywD5MT@+]?J.p-955y:P[a5+>e,]d(s%0qV|R,[Jy&9B;OgbL?(yy$&PM-LvBrM][r8Hf_pM^$#JyBG+]MBf=-`aO`4P[Jy$(+]{\,c!dtcQu+S~\}:=>qVSi2Y@_';|3pApNY[/oIe`TpIg1"kqF-0R^^O2~+TDem74!pAJSY[1`eS\)~dU9?+K::{@VQX]TT0'hCP~\W7!+#'^/rK~cS4pA&wN&6SEWXdEi5-i2!vkF-0$S?(ETiq:sfb_.a5AY;{NmQX[EG92`NSFoV[
2023-09-07 02:20:32.486 32460-32460 crashpad                pid-32460                            A  1S_8.){t{9B?H+U#PCGB^}'OL6Qo[HVs'T@F:iLOa,~iBPSP#uNQrO'BNuZXq>W0Bev/Iy:C+]{i9ZuTTAiy?g~>z+^/1K*]{UoYMz7U~\Y8=>5*!Qx]^y|:P_>}=ho-2g6-$v[ehhne~>d9=>OP)]Wvf)b3mrqiURuS*,{4uAwTT-D%pA|T#0Z]#J4YjC63Jy0f/-T@$MUCvmIok^j`^4w!'B<2RZ$T}WAkxW5MvyY[AlcR~GAE37$nV[OR_8z/U)n]4c+.X5+>7'j0U`l0+[Iy0f`9qP/+[46cFeUYH6'V.fH-uu0|;AhD\N=,5M*k'Bt&5+Teil*(ab#}#0M2)]uj4;O$5M82-fN}+2K!A6s``m~/"$Mesf+E`iWt)23,9}e5&?6?&NVa&f!96+K::]eU?-(3f6fxX@X5uS<'2TLM|K>MlfJsO(|t%Q,l]=pE]1i2aFD+Hf'Bpn=R?BC?j~^&pA>;Q(pNwHQMBD;AFoV[u}$8.X;of%~WXx~\9N#0
2023-09-07 02:20:32.486 32460-32460 crashpad                pid-32460                            A  $Pop'L.f-eu*{Bss%,J}U8E*D53;q!5Mf9+]?W~MtP9Bg9W"pA&QY[M-(s+cHW6;IJ5[icsmE,ed'^!G?V~\MZt9s|5ZV4F6}iB/od^4OMmcO+ctR}BYmL~\E:)TRzEk03mqf0T5+>7'nbp\?>Xgw(<(pARaxyQJE$oVrr-2Vn-Otl9?z-^/ltGHPu}WB-pA@N#0`pX\82#;32JyB'.o'+si,]y^:TX#,QwOY[c,+`wP"QKV{Be,+]YlXO4W~i#fUs;>s91=M!v3m2-;)=JyTP+TLA*uVtO'c-pAr]&:4qN+.}{Cb;l`Ko>wRRAYEW%?0DfU)dU#^Z'BFA>i#S-0TEHoV[5R?(aB+HB;>2^A5M&9j7)l#FIw>}l^ZZgmfKER?(e\kA>!37os;>!:]s8?{4Em53[3/d5M*K'B^Cg<4>3<7PTv^4!F$<7?P\]KFW[/v*z05M,,+]_.Rh&VFKi2^oV[4.@PY4SKHHTd}r>+$-7{t(r}pm=.)jmc~>@.6[A\
2023-09-07 02:20:32.486 32460-32460 crashpad                pid-32460                            A  %?ZAy-Yi5M&qg-LLH6}JhX@U6POv+o"I#R+>u2Y[W+Lc`=U#Te'Bp\VRe=*?E*foV[!SuSp`%o?Su1>/1&!f.c),&Jt<feaYc5-obFeq>BxrJY!I+G@p{3B>S9K:(@U)0fTB#^U5+>6'tudLAYu{(*abQD<SaTP+x5Ka(h=k*Gc[ER+>W!7JWPS1>/0&'y%,.}.Q'OJjx:+.3Mxiz7)TUZ?DP1h[jkU#Lq.^sa)w5,[8_)t).4/OQJ;]U~l3(qZLF/pAxRY[34gShOFeiC~I]/m;MeLj%slf^L\4WV{B+?+]yTAKG18D7"[e~>WI#/qR)]Oso)!kAUbnLV4Vjx'ON]P'=2ab[)&?AJicNZ%q#49N~\9oy<Ff*J&]4diCO@{B:O'BNu;<~S}iHx~f~><,6[%-no4[n7"Habm^|9Zc0Q?(Z4OBql^5ml8'nbvPSXk[@UY-U#~J.c/o[Xo/SF7v6PIy*K'BLR7i:>!@aFGQrl9?EHjD6tEd*bV+379nV[;R
2023-09-07 02:20:32.486 32460-32460 crashpad                pid-32460                            A  uSJ-KH:CLr(FabO3&?l2fp`;k(g1`g~>@.6[%Q^gXoD1N?B+_$cVOVb;{B!lu?~VNJ-A6'd=f}HA@fwfTe~>\7)TP3Gtt(53-d7+}1$WX9Zc3cR6LWNk41pA"O#060zZhCGWj)B(U#PC'BN-IOZR39]dOs'T2Ks2#o`mfZ/P,R$KwdJ9,Nzcl87PzAg1vb~>\,,ff1wH)Y(DwJte~>/uu97]cDajMuCY~f\5%LW-GNjPB\hCo'/&'Y'BvY#Jv%eHo-W#4Uui\>&Bfw*U{nW#pSW-o%.}yBxfA35M27rR;Ae8#f7>-D!p|VU]I:+]+`"Ju\\gCU*s;>j9#f@$-lS:[wzI+f;A)skC&BP^0U>QqlT5]\9{n]YbS}E2~O/&eh-cUB(ho\lB^a[CX#<Y'B0N?/p]%PV+5P~\Um\h5o27Hf:AuiE:*gL5<'R4jP'O#CDL6/5MXB+]wk9ZajD;CVX8,J5[?-qSU%notd;AU0bc$qqshDLX6M-oR4,qGnV[GRi-
2023-09-07 02:20:32.486 32460-32460 crashpad                pid-32460                            A  I){t?wS2':.&u0.N8:;Kc3c13`<+]s+1mnsG$JxKFC=b3iT5Yr-'"L!Xq>I#iy?g~>0.^/`(cvUCV%,9;ofK(vK-vTxvUTcOjKBs;>WOu?AKMXjV&I~r;>v9K:}!mFicbP-9~I+fLalRNZm4~}Td8dHqB+ac9.}P2]wUC2:UC+W`9'<ikmxBR*Ir%q1J+foKWhh(@KWQ<BkBJ6iGiZ'Bt&|KF(Hc_.b5uS8'DMwW=BMd9U8Ya5UCxa%QF?}Xx+l[,-m>ds=g3'2T(8#fLEt<lnV[4.6[5I]KJIfApd1&I:.cSu=,c<pQ:AK[Iy&1bR!IAO$'O9#\0lX5Yr-'*P:N;A`<m^,?ab'/&?{t%b^b*BwJ2d~>)tt9zFW<x/\:'hgX2JSlHRUCf7#`$b)BE2R5uSRB6ozMP.#\4o5J+fCwF/$wop_(\cw8JYRJaK<-=Y#b4@b?tba,pAPV'HF5/6Wv$Blp7+U/8{xrIj.*9WU#,AY.x(j+7?*YC]i3ig*Dn9=>
2023-09-07 02:20:32.486 32460-32460 crashpad                pid-32460                            A  QaYu)M^Cr[6J5[_weaj47^iC6-a[,&KKn6]*HmT0>TV+-4I5{K,Nt(NXo/i+biPb~>2-U@zLA\M]-`L:Iy(*+]_ZymhCW=uH3f:mlV@!xHmk=KGh&BfNTg~>H,7[`1$s!UH"oU~\g;?>|W]T^c|R,nV[&.6[-QFkd=l1JTpQ~\S4?8t.[4^7:Fq^Z](7=p&.^/p5*]+eq0{Aabyx#0"a*]W'KEO-ab#}'HF5Y[Y4Z40ger;>,:1=gxUCj9'a:Eab}fCR'O\PuS!/*,0%xdBUPOxJY[-Fy,4Y1&/=.cCYsz^%So`f-&I:.cSA>,QCdPjSZ5UC$77C}eqab{,[#F3l$MR2ob$e|A;]OKQ<E&P?>:}I]/F-=Y93-TMfHv!}~\=:)Td`eB4PV+S{~\O2Q-S4eB@(r0nvmd14&?)4J\&24:+&92.c{=eP@VcDfR<+-[9{"waWr4e\+]K2oF-0\NK^4_:c#fIEb35MvyY[7LeP,Tccis;>!:U/$QviBU2N~\w7
2023-09-07 02:20:32.486 32460-32460 crashpad                pid-32460                            A  )T$=2O&qVKvBr5%Y?1TWJnKeMalc8*?+V6}}t(Y[Xwf[j+W#Z(X,61ly?(ik'.l^f}nt*7=>!r*][GAUO|X#hO'BpnE\ApcFAoMpiS~\!8+`#MAY'qclMb~>l,@P?3Y[Y(c)rDABiGG1r87?Df%?r)$.!M5MF)+]a_#N0n:C}s~f~>4.^/u-yq\t134J5[M-c<t8_$m)zT0n~/R|Di[/'cUBQ?S]2V^l\0&?@4zMxJ:2~O,&=TNOJKY[c`B(9+U/5{0fJ7[BzFITJyR/+]AH){0NI1$2&$6tfQ%s%l*u0Q0HsS\nV[WRuSh\fkXwEM}f~>~-,f.5)]MbEVMC5M"O%S)DD]um^]_-L1ZfT:)TH2wd&\KE+?ab{)&?2m_Pvi$%mU~\W7=>oEa2c5Cn]S(o5MjsJ-Lrj/#0X]s31FiR^lh-&?[$PMWtL5l|}M~\c9)T%3%?t0u$:lO5uSZ,EX(}aFtiJ9lL~\Q4A8LZb8|]mTzsTm~/<Qs9'-vzltdDHj-s
2023-09-07 02:20:32.486 32460-32460 crashpad                pid-32460                            A  -K\-,f]6#BtlD1SaWs;>c9m{@}+>u=WIp5V5uS0'd=k;lfN<@o[8Mb~>N-^/RJ%?7K'.-35M(b,.Z;y&$-lQpP3emsol99n.ZPUCS+9g5,Z5uS.'\)ZPuS}1OB/1pA4P][.9W`3TwN(8gXV4sX(V,QuSf3oU/t-&'Y'B6Guz0&\I:5Z5uS6'j0J9-[EuYG9J5[K-)/C8K:$qyVrN~\55?-+w5K2rEF?2O53_9'd-/i>>}I]/R-c<lX\[or;>1:m{^4=>/T8$bs{rA5G*$=y_%B>=cNsW.fFr+V#08\){YQrf+.\5!IR-I?m*T@9BJgfl.&afHQc@=uye4PK^qh;+<+&b-cSu\7U/&qy'(c~>H;=>%L&cEjB]M|+&5P-cy8P&03QB}t.=abEJy9dE6"v3+sP1xDJ<eDRRUCZAzelt^Q{z~\a8=>e0#BfKY:Tn~/LQZZ%5xkaB,fIn|B6t'B&a><ZPF5e]U5+>3'd=U<t^a[&<!<IynU~+Va%N7d%4yn7$
2023-09-07 02:20:32.486 32460-32460 crashpad                pid-32460                            A  1J</'BJY<<^180LxdnV[4.T:3*#09b$Zwr;>SO`>>,E]tK}nV#RTncu"L}ClZjVn~/PKgRy.F,)of||:<K9+Nr:{dpq1LG=?iXIy40+]E>1taF@wSf`e^5abc-&?wufuVu3/Zl_|~\W6"Y_4}MxrFd5=cv)nR|`FsBp9#f<r|M50u?:^~-xdATdO}up]*]}fkI<'/&Q~GBz{uS(<X`Z:5Ml,+]c]-{&16)/9D.xdw].c}j}A)ouST;)V.f(SlR$UrMIg@'-&'Y'BJY<H*]}F.FsRyNwpaA=6~cR,$NZS}DWYSVA+ZzBC5jRal_7ea4sN*gj08O~'(qL},G09`h{W:7<n@H%,g$Dk8g!m}4Gu~*DmN"2K>I1v+_bW'#GqNp?rUGe2}O?1uM`K{W<IDpo\-`@6gF,V#b$I8hVpwvpVJdmvi``"j-z*@}&u7Dn,`Zhuq)Vm/8Hu|KMIUG17d3b'a1$QC3KPpd^'R[4ObI5>H]=Itu3q;Q[K+4-{^_}N/ICn
2023-09-07 02:20:32.487 32460-32460 crashpad                pid-32460                            A  <w(F)_,*dBhjaoa`iN(_2cj;Jk;k-M$=s\8AD)eG/]Iw"ZvfUql8l]LWne;I4dEQ7x(3aT&\=.1r%eLqp@)l2dLl%dA|,c'KB[8VeWs<OS@[#fJG9oxv{?f1&Pz4rK.2"RxJI+ehqV3p~Rf`S4'F&4R{xi:^6?XcR4;P9OHYQ^gg,,nISDbUFtQ^t]^_q-\q:dXZA*Lpz*x4{+ZR3ikj,^n`~4YFFuk@kYPL*y3y4_I>qSTlNwiYLLS2mqQ.N1>ol2Rk.gnQGEQ("k3@nU~hRndtLT'GXdKGG9CCI)YpMvLO$G`dhJZ]!HFwb^B.ya'TihrinHvF~j^0!r_@D;%LjW!&q4{}Y?di33gJ-<SK"Lgv~a$8l@)9&p1\8kV[wQgL\}uZ2gMu<)Cu7goaCeNwxn8MNjK+zG6{TF$c?]c/!Zhc-NX[-1X.z<ip$/(e^;3><W?k=_6[WNc4vg,+8UO1}Xy[>XJ&%.>FG_i:Oaa@4;dDuHc>@9F<LN0luSzKEv0Z
2023-09-07 02:20:32.487 32460-32460 crashpad                pid-32460                            A  !4B+Qxl4t6l/I?Q7;`9q~%h/_a}EBkT|DhE5J3o^^T{%upS$Q%q8!mPzU:9_-b=qn4yL.<lq\2,c);S!?i1i!E%+*b-9k]ook\2t.6XG^otWTF`V9nY1PI+f/5e0AVgo'L0.frh@`?)@upF<=:nq`uElUr3L>ppH^AFh~K:VgkC+wr?_.~k8!7,Q.are%^{F!=flDVJ~&e$CvX}D>>9/C:<4JGK<<q*GqquaB*@188MrfThvr3?TH<S9Q/mGP4puFFJ[*wQ*AJ^N%_.-EXwWJrO(>@qc^POuHS@MyDoWLc~p.I@g1di7IaZ_0n!F`TEr4,~mVee*GTjjwf$T;@|]Gl<HCUV^x9c/uhgQyZB/#J\,Ys.#m)AfkZ~\<nMLT_dD6V(-8TPZTv:Pr_%-Ph=hQUP\gK^p!_}s2@wT~]=C:_p,@@CFKFp[<@N4ylsDYoi[>uwAp?Y7t1F9o*Pho/JVMh2LgsUjfg&52H[5N_?op8Y&P[!7Y/bSt9Fth[Na6U~p
2023-09-07 02:20:32.487 32460-32460 crashpad                pid-32460                            A  g6u^pVigEjn[{Sk.xMJ{4j;Bo:hFN*"@I,bj[27Ah8J?y9h)tvo,i^]W#(uj}Y,^nH@>\DaotG_AI[oKsm*)o@c;pG~[dw}r40~CRUS\\@pSkgHv,9=y6w>x1,77-:dcpgft^6:7W5kD(TQ4r({/ZlvX=!Dh+Ff>Y5GW[1$dxo~lU#~P?sAqNYw;XwF-ok+#no[;9>Rk-m|h"k<s.``VSC@cWGvNidHV+:DH91\`6\#kVARk#lNZz{H_(.!prh>%mu!5La3F=r8DQ6\%6w;Sb:;>f$HIhd\{-4=@A?9_ZnZ6KY|w-rmh~QVDEU=1uLN,>mV{}9nhthFlU?PCG;^("G.LfF?.$2&^=jPxcUR4_6}]RQ;ap`;VSqnQ-w7UrwS0Bn`,&CYWXFBtt-Gwwp>Ag=0_:q73-m<i;lo2Cc%ct8wOe!f',I.NQCe_AF\`_A&H6P&t089?:pag?h/d9V=HwvRVNI^0ciN^+^oF$9AF:y5<Upr2HA!t_\/6!<$mIl&L
2023-09-07 02:20:32.487 32460-32460 crashpad                pid-32460                            A  kgXaF%]+c?|M'#fMfP@HZ*d85g~8#OYk>qxYb|W+:by9Xwm3eTT5tj:t>6hGj+;_8*]E1|RcJ){>u8j-v{^'#cV\IWwa?dOa/~|4~Q|a.5i-<+"N(`xt21IYRetN(Vo9^JysL}=rUJ}Ufcjc^*!(l}QF6gJ)-hC\h`"U"R,CS':b*OZtV:"{r"i9D:ClUpx"h]f;=DPibdPV|ad]\|Pk%0hHn}R,Vh?g9VD6C5</DXPIKjr:>;8^U6i+.6(yoej!D*`;dtI9S[7L6r\()ZZH-ZBZWx<FB>BB[xj(},(S:b45]Qz8W_~dopWo1r[m{Hgl'HJT*F`wW;^I&;Gge8<ZYqsP7?T])<=DTOKsn%uZd5|s{Q$U`lVQPA_X*r+1N(ol(0GnE8Kh/<4h1uwhF5qx],0jjM&bDXs_Yt6IOa6L>;:>eIFG=BB\EGCUC(ZT9ov9NCM2OJ%i(o?WYglFGsiA(]a9zTa9`5&HIE/rIwFphj3mr|!20t.++j;Cx8BMcMki
2023-09-07 02:20:32.487 32460-32460 crashpad                pid-32460                            A  Lt@}*n}R]\p8`C&}+3NV*J}4|A7}}1"7H&\EZodVgAFWC[YM-rbf5H2,Z4PZF%:LYpvO+Dv7CQ^0D+jL!@hm}f@EmQrRLEj0QQ=Hrhm9l[H?;&Xql(061>b^eb`sY4[C*A*QG\)D++/Jxaiv#5mCh32FdcYf0KZ,{@O5rf_J),r#&IqFEQ|Yd@!MO4vB@RMp4B^2?q!pP&l{kY$Zt]oW_A9A5Z|84F8/#,%]/)v5R-FjscRq,gQq5ofv,Mn8O,8r;>R|jkCNYa!,<0{q:<G1ls>,yj<h27bl7j'1"+(g{n,Boye5)WOFjv{%!_G_Su`62bqy*FcC<U*5&RlO.E|z[tgpsw}HvnZg-pr[Q<0;-h@r'E^Y"2R/aw`-kQ_F7.Losf]+LT4G2g+L*#uH;WEyX3icx'5&w)mo~U|wSoxSW?bB2o8`n{b#wakiqJ~mePy96V{;{BFTRLGK^d!6TcZEutH3Vr4U_mT[$j7B/\/Vud*?CP0sz<KIQhwINk^]HHvN
2023-09-07 02:20:32.487 32460-32460 crashpad                pid-32460                            A  |4I|Y+dh`(<)f`*V~%Tw?bSl;kgEP3rD8rZYL?M1'?Z=%pc>ff-u|IKM&xD5W>2L>v`$Ahv1LD)/Dwkf*wm)rE4d\^@D~a@0IZM~R??W),+pil@7,)z0^l^hS:`kS=kWe%YB|V:``ZhQrbDt"czV%hcY3t~uJV3z`+pT`p{w8;1t7PeDXey(+wd*ZA|`EqXPLvUX'X,?D+D[\tdmhttvdOxORgtFTGo%'DEMFrQ8&'1MO059&Eu8&-xCjkS;HhY3;oCJb]A_C3XsL$)qy*OkNKh;nAbf|Q.r}tjwv]AtU[4n^fOhoZd5cgA6)A8#)p&U!VnzTs_0.])D3C'iin%GTeM;enN?5w`V*F$Om(W~T@F7fE^n'}j+]Fx(ko652<&>h|wNHZpJ4XmhLC(Fz3+ST%W*R2_o_A>Jl|"J|R_uyo#KIBz<$o~k,z[7q\T8%'Fk8:EK'gEsNkg(9KcQ|X1YTDO+G)CwPusOXIFbr\8`6_luy3`i`Cz^>-nXm(HFOg(#
2023-09-07 02:20:32.487 32460-32460 crashpad                pid-32460                            A  Q=MYQA*Hg,\i*1gmAyf5f3Itkc({mUBPMem9,0qU^R;W;)BsCE'jwR83F{L@_%TSBJ(QIvRf-r_i@E1merX4M`X.XVJf2K%`dtx,%uLH4wJTBv,P0?cE!~dL4y7`Ot2_5f{foS>FLo^?<gj?~qhd|4+:"YRaAkpuZGwjxDDUh>s185eG8AHH0q4g^vTI#/>pL.,KvFSD_l;G+X2V'a`e!6(9H'[`E%boKF!_GIq[49NF)*nqLB\pkONck5zrcRfXzKq\';?D6A#h:B{O2W>N_g,">dOdUCkJ2r)J$h{]&89uxA41]8lSGFrhknL>lCQc)Vb;9sL[I>y-VEF&}q8bOT0I+WLt;GVAS82=j{pl4qEp\M[R1A>3/Nr==Ut22/x)b5f^b3D=9ryBE2w3MX@qd;Ab)7T9n<'`,0sai.r1hJFYGx('x^kA=brUKgodQ\vM|#4sP3LP|#++Fnx_^g/ah}6nZ)s/h/2bbDolXwarJi9N{B+9EFPK{06EEXA{`uq5
2023-09-07 02:20:32.487 32460-32460 crashpad                pid-32460                            A  L_@rQ[mI#ZKo@;#RcPSh5.a?N%1D8+"/LU$9(5>5Io8roa57Vhl:#L/z61P+@i\vRht[54\0zhP?e683*SNLF5_I~*f5h|qNj9n9Cn-KcipsR\~pNLQp\rNyuU7_NkfW#K}K5r?CSK[_16]wRvF=0uUTbwJLjg~IGM67|1I]Dfxo/ZAl:W%tv;Ueg+D[*rde{3+IrN8pU\7_V3nJl*\wpZ?YPqskp:_FRVNY_p7h'@H\7]6t'<>p&_<Xmq$tWc>v>k]aV[>vmjdIX8Pqhj3JVaw_@0]ZsE-TRL@w9J^J.qsr3vwid3OC~j!ip9q\3Le81flA,+SP[CfD=U?XOTLyGjpN^\K1s%S\BX/bs^Dr(Ir+cko5!FlF%D6bfe=p7A]d#-oeuq.v,anp}mmDH~>r&"5]L[F.e)h=Cnw+L|Oo_0hVM?qkKA8w9\925<7oa?ci4/kexH61qshHrs\q:N"b%@lq_vb<%@'I|BG%x%xC;?gV\ZW2(/-*)j)vIU{Sp?=K
2023-09-07 02:20:32.487 32460-32460 crashpad                pid-32460                            A  a+dgNK11O!bdoW7OMZ?1OUd:d)ccI;RB%I$/xtzPJCDhEN6H3*hS>p`+hWa.7F,&n<JEfoC@1y$Vb[TcG2AtRFHXVt'3j]YpAKwq4;1y?1BPfV>p9lMpv09u1[OJy*)xli^:)j_BSvr|<7"$$^Mcx_bR6Wqm62?1B[83P8%s:i}\BR@I\A]PpE\0WaL.>jUkW1&Q8fgwkThZ\Z6`utWu#L)|u@mlnRj6m&T/xCIj(W*+Fk32Dq"cDn/LIgMYJn9+_d)d'xaEDO.U.3ALB%[f*0{z&6!?PnqfrmR4cttP]g"3WBydMLf5<SOE\d%ZkcF>m23oT]Q["J40cGPg.m1LSb=Bf%|8#H.KA>7uq3$jE=P\}ikk[ckPvd!<vJVLo[|N>2T[(m5O5vgBGmTYF0js-8JW\zHdpTK[LB,;X]J+?fx[^V$KJ^.6iQ8]5>%,kPhD,Od=*M(wZgzq{aS]%@#Uig;jqB`F=Na~#r/'*HcZYejjDfO|h_,oJanF~ws@Aq|o
2023-09-07 02:20:32.487 32460-32460 crashpad                pid-32460                            A  "e4^#;JdaN$*"W~/(w|[ts~l52\dBSqry/<A[hUIDwSv</8`6?-z7J|\JB1(k\xI<ADtgZh)[wY_zUCu[ggBKwnJYEkYBYDei+|'s.VK$VH]mBwsXo]IL_-O~Z:`G\2G2A&TED$316$iC^^98aclgfWp_\A:HK?$(ta(qJ]ng`!j$lP@Sr)LNPnH40dCuYE\RkQ*x}q<TDIBFuVe>Fh6hV8o$k<lhmcoCp'c:<HQX(gSMq:3~rS|yVQ=eYtC2@tKXP8Iu)kh|Jk;^+h/"XmI-}m\V_5Q`A_5kq<@ce0mG,0^KO:r-q=u@up(u@%S2wu^Nhp(9vT3,y0A"HhNeN-}znP)fi"+4bQ.772Ev;LlgU\E[V[s6dRAdG"6)[k(.H{)+I}{_1}*V`fVrTRqP`'O).[:UtT-Kd[w]PFDFZ=qXa=5`iC+qrsuNhl|R]~0Hju^Pc8L0Zf@:/@V&tnJXNH_Cr*r[\ML\ympBW5l*KoELL@5um@qhT8QX)*l1VHC~\-<
2023-09-07 02:20:32.487 32460-32460 crashpad                pid-32460                            A  0UavjbU2OGIcJDmlxHqAd5\5uWFFm^&3:LHf1\0+EdTsvVLi<r*l,`l1~i4tnq|RtMGw[>_[a?<!c[$ykk8\kO5/WA;uZkuQ3l1u`uy]E\gbpq<fYgzzn^$r(imoww`kVX8j):^Tdp$+PYx2Rp0?l^h97uKk<cW["sZUbxGW#D<53HE@mtOKj$`G1DUDn\9`f)BcT%b]<Wbj7}";!Aru|GiftlFD9_lQ'e"59^"k_>t4<"$r(bHI$$4g4]5mMS>C0E2JE=ggs|Rl!/4WCg5Xfb!ucUwOvl['x|,o\/~u#0OpB#LuW/DU0l>k2L@wqJElV,2_Ht)i<OBWlCB`VQDAFg(q^24q`u\,^r$&IX1-eX!Q~p@hkJ%QB+>?<AvOWf&O%L@IF<T\0Jw>I7sPwJ]Y>_.6L;{(:gXH\f~=^?#^f*_ES[$it9iT'UkW+5*Hc,Toh4Ud9\LL0^(vK),EKn282L8hZuP.etO$L0Ifp@PECg_H5hY(TPXeSfZ'`f9VO\Da
2023-09-07 02:20:32.487 32460-32460 crashpad                pid-32460                            A  i>u`.+9ZjH'}Y"g[VSifRdCW(8fJ-i{Hrt6(k]?+dmovf{lOj+eOn.EvYC)Kn|p3SaKP-4[FU`po.aY=5(JJ6KW_yq(ImQEL|B8Gy9Nai8p]H[EB&1Bpjh{l{qH2)wcoNY_9NV$4!F2<Z_0Sk[H.S;-."v3@(L))$tXw}9{tElGf9Hvo5uuV$y|5;(/qR_iQv#Z[<E-L{V0\Dq)fZT[FU}yZCHeFHyp>.~@`>13a0S34?Q66-m83Mq_-Hmk\CwcK7?^=D-SR@fBMyVEVT.v.<*vFrU&w8UDtLFwM}QQv#dSZjdX@gB6n~t*gQr:NVuS+ru6b[t^^|NK'iqYPL]Ykzrs0eGvQ&n(YR6kk56^aO1us?<hDmVyX@Oz_vFR>Nrxw)9ve6ZstVMYpT_,M3>u[8=All\WZbi\f!r]_nZgE;w`NiO2?b'lKhOJX!-Th+sW+D81P|@)hX&'X&yI[jPCWXFR\3@z<7rHs$}S/IXk*@R[3NvK0EC.sxX7XDw!G$l`u
2023-09-07 02:20:32.487 32460-32460 crashpad                pid-32460                            A  xh(.fuSggh|K7Rd^>*O1TDs[}`l]HkL[B`^P;kh6veP)<1adcnWHml^ve`Ih#GDIlE3]lD~1rC]zze+7Pi}kV)=J~U*&,4L{;\st:FS]6t~t*nn]96}InX!N|@^2ym9\4@[]jn@K\c.t`TxOkJdX1jaYp4hk3m^9lSLLVk=8:kiq+qpquic519i8#j..fR-2W]eVBDN:RrBo!k41xPHr9e(5ur/JzLiK)Qwa*e\h5a,aXG*6yBcC?V}%|c%ZfjtY>r|KzJ5pZOoFk>mZla]F%v?u]DxxZBT.bB{h1L]a|(3}VUEd(FCp)u3JYU=>#MNck)Wq{CB2.mBR>-vK=D\GfT_5g~~Yv2gd(EelA`\v29I?FK0]<wrrl;0i:>Y?iFv`~4Plo~"$8^vL>,P5{;L`Neu4$isoDs3bwpksq>BwxI!F1_mh75Al!8[JHR>7l$~J[F-J11y>/2oEqei2eY`r8rp_GtZrilbV]h]wk?/\fl:olGw/4TFw"jZ6~H(mgG43
2023-09-07 02:20:32.487 32460-32460 crashpad                pid-32460                            A  50a6,9nDes0`:uApVrNO;v<BD>E9pq5qRYl8};{ct4$ZiR>(x[)?I^u2fp-AAlk-NEE4(V"FbvEeJv<=E>xleQ]kb$PT:~jR5>_DmbpdU24wRH?GuV~l8M(05N`/2=vt'N/qBGj.%~l:hoH9h@GFrsm`JIPIeV)w#)~dP62cb<~H#P&$UvPg!3Dt;J0RaWntsx5^27Zps0s3eMR[w*qz<P|Ghij(B\}R4wX.&mn[CsWhhSr7FUS)m)M`THGVYKK[wC)BA@hIRdy>@i&sf?.@hqt>PUHX$E==NK_r0IPobF-Q,d"<y]f0*Q[@B=-D|UD_:l7]2H2h1cUHX}w17sUq5/+qg5ashZyo>uxa4^Y[H=B)8N'a;?`\*v^{Nrs+rlM=/e-u>H/kVXzIqLQXVOxv7f!b*O&hUly`SA8N(5ivbPoI=Dfa_Dz.'H$Hc@y)`D;gKvRt$iGKln%@8j&I1-zj"d[[7SL:d4VAPQ:I,1yDhw9WGrLgC8QCh)7V?h@=6w,.
2023-09-07 02:20:32.487 32460-32460 crashpad                pid-32460                            A  kBIrxFuZgYX\:c5-(iED,mF0L:<]93.]tFn-"m/>$1@i"x!k,+*dW4iASrFb@zJ2j[pqK^,r&zuVd9/qyr0jhpqi0LdNS7r`2,c_+3.H,1Xgh:Xv:<zJvtlKb2%6?MuliNppD/Wb1uB#7MCn7IQUN@,u2\&SVmMIz1zp\lwhD_<gDU[u>(bBH%BcN$)YUP.HUX_Z$I|GiF^JZvGw)Wz<&1ntyOfq?d6B@y"V!~1*Jt~4-V-TmCsO\D+qL(]8fos<}tlfHv+qy>il<T_Dk74Rs?dPKAjfZU4Kztp56JjDF)%:~_+G\X0wPR=aj3C4<huRI_gFLrwM(mf6sCvG\1U[H9h1Tl&7,2Q]9:A?:KEj}i[9GUX;4v*k*05w05uo(AN*^6ia{pai7&=I~26H.XHFO_B((:`JW[5mK([CrQUym9iqeG`Bfa.gt\(^|gCg/)|HCW{s!l75TiD\6^BW8QIVjVfRx/)6jYT)LnT_/;y.rfLUCaZ?3@&=:W2}<G{,R`,|
```

I expected this [full screen function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50103945/13639872) are implemented in my coding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, if you're intending to use a WebView inside Jetpack Compose, it's much better to use this special library which is basically an optimized wrapper for WebViews in Jetpack Compose. Here's the link [Google Accompanists WebView Compose](https://google.github.io/accompanist/web/)

The usage is very simple:

1- Instead of using wrapping a standard WebView inside an AndroidView using factory, the library will do it for you, so do this instead:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun MyContent(activity: ComponentActivity) {
  val state = rememberWebViewState(url = "www.google.com")
  val navigator = rememberWebViewNavigator()
  val chromeClient = remember { CustomChromeClient(activity) }


  WebView(
    state = state,
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    navigator = navigator,
    chromeClient = chromeClient, //This is what concerns us for fullscreen mode
    onCreated = { webView -> 
        //configuring the webview settings here such as enabling javascript
    }
  )
}
```

2- Now to answer your question and solve the problem, in order to make the webview go to fullscreen mode, you should implement a custom `WebChromeClient`and override some of its methods to control what happens when the view goes to fullscreen mode. In our case, I created a new class called `CustomChromeClient` which extends `AccompanistWebChromeClient` (which is basically an optimized WebChromeClient for Jetpack Compose), then I overrode the methods related to creating custom views, this is how it's done:

```kotlin
class CustomChromeClient(val activity: ComponentActivity): AccompanistWebChromeClient() {

    var customView: View? = null

    override fun onHideCustomView() {
        (activity.window.decorView as FrameLayout).removeView(this.customView)
        this.customView = null

    }

    override fun onShowCustomView(paramView: View, paramCustomViewCallback: CustomViewCallback) {
        if (this.customView != null) {
            onHideCustomView()
            return
        }
        this.customView = paramView
        (activity.window.decorView as FrameLayout).addView(this.customView, FrameLayout.LayoutParams(-1, -1))
    }

}
```

**In principle**: When you try to launch something from WebView into fullscreen mode (like a video on some website), it's not the WebView itself that goes into fullscreen mode, but actually, it shows that content in *another* webview which is passed as a parameter in those override methods as you can see, so we need to always keep a reference to it. So, when our main WebView gives us a new WebView which will be our fullscreen WebView, we can actually add it as a direct child to the whole FrameLayout for the activity (yes, every activity is basically a FrameLayout with stuff inside it), and voilà, you can show things that cover the whole screen using this trick, not just full screen webviews, but a lot of other stuff!

And that's it ! By using a custom chrome client and overriding those methods to control how fullscreen is executed, we make a WebView that supports fullscreen in Jetpack Compose.

Comment: I try to follow your code given but I receive [error](https://prnt.sc/8E4K0mg3-xoi)

Comment: @SyahmiSam I modified the code to adapt it to your way of doing things, you should at least pass "activity" to your composable because we need it inside our WebChromeClient... I also removed the explicit "WebViewClient" parameter from the webview because we're not using a custom webviewclient, so the accompanist webview will use the default implementation for it. Try the modified code now

Comment: New code given, there is no errors but I still can't run app. Can you help me, what is the [problem](https://prnt.sc/I6A5qlLrOwQQ)

Comment: @SyahmiSam Bro, post the logcat crash stacktrace so we could identify the problem. There is nothing wrong with the code.

Comment: Now I can run my app but when I try to full screen for youtube video it goes crush. seems like have error on full screen function. [logcat](https://prnt.sc/rZRo7Tao-qkr)

Comment: @SyahmiSam Post your entire activity's jetpack compose code (edit your main post), as I said before the code is correct and it works just fine on my end. You're just calling it wrong

Comment: I have edit my main post. Hopefully you can solve my problem.

Comment: @SyahmiSam Why are you passing another instance of `MainActivity` as a parameter for your composable ? Passing `MainActivity()` means you're creating a new copy of your activity and passing it, and creating a new activity like that means you're creating an empty shell that is linked to nothing not even a window, so what you should be doing is passing your CURRENT main activity instance... to do that: you should pass the activity using "this": `MyContent(this@MainActivity)` . This way, it should work.

Comment: I try to add TopAppBar but when I try to full screen video, the app crash. I appreciate if you help me once more. I have update new code and logcat.